# URLs not matching when admin page set to root url in django app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I building a Django app with DRF, but the API URLs do not match correctly when I set the admin site at the root URL

root URL pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', admin.site.urls),
path('api/auth/', include("account.urls")),
path('api/main/', include("main.urls")),
```

]

main URL pattern:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('language', LanguageView)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    
]
```

when I hit the main API URLs it returns the admin login page, can't fix this yet
please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Include the admin as the last entry in your urls, otherwise your api urls will never match because they are "valid" admin paths and will always be handled by the admin

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth/', include("account.urls")),
    path('api/main/', include("main.urls")),
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working